# Why can't I download TagHelpers (nuget & ASP.NET 5)?

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I can't get the TagHelpers package via the project.json nor through nuget.

I've tried [>Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers -Pre](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers/)  in the package manager console.

I can't even find it in the Nuget Package Manager search.

I'm using the latest Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6 with everything up to date. I started using the ASP.NET 5 web project.

How can I get the TagHelpers package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the NuGet console. It will not work. 
Use `kpm`:

```
kpm add Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers
kpm restore
```

Also, check the NuGet package sources in the VS options. Make sure nuget.org is enabled.

Comment: kpm add worked but restore gives me a "kpm : 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command" error. I restored all the references in the project and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

You can use nuget just fine. The problem is the CTP6 includes a nuget v3 api reference, which is active by default, but that doesn't work with nuget properly.

To fix this:

1. Go into Tools -> NuGet Package manager -> Package Manager Settings.
2. On the left click Package Sources.
3. On the right you should see 'nuget.org' and 'api.nuget.org'. The api one will probably be checked, while the nuget.org one will not.
4. Ensure 'nuget.org' is checked, and the other is not.
5. Click the nuget.org entry and ensure the 'source' textbox has a v2 instead of v3 in the url.

Done.

Comment: I checked them both (prepared for v3 to go live) and it works.